# How to add image to Bootstrap navbar-brand without being a broken image?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I can't seem to find a way to make my image appear in the navbar. Any tips on whether I should add a div tag or an extra class? What should I do in terms of CSS? I'm new to Bootstrap, thanks!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-b navbar-trans navbar-expand-md fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll" href="#page-top" >
        <img src="img/Signature2.png" id="brand-image" class="img-fluid"/>
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarDefault" aria-controls="navbarDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </button>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll active" href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll" href="#work">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll" href="#blog">Art</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and replaced it with another image (since I cannot access yours) and it works. So the problem may be in the path you're providing.

Is the img folder in the same level as the html you linked? Are you sure you named the folder and image correctly?